# Azure DevOps 2019 Services - GitHub Azure Pipelines App - Remove 1 of 2 build pipeline associations to GitHub repository

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have Azure DevOps 2019 Services project AA pointing to the GitHub repository XX for an Azure DevOps 2019 Services BUILD pipeline. CI integration is enabled via the GitHub Azure Pipelines App. The BUILD pipeline builds automatically for commits to GitHub master and its associated PRs.  It works as it should.

I have to switch from project AA to Azure DevOps 2019 Services project BB.

I have Azure DevOps 2019 Services project BB pointing to the same GitHub repository XX for an Azure DevOps 2019 Services BUILD pipeline. CI integration is enabled via the GitHub Azure Pipelines App. The BUILD pipeline builds automatically for commits to GitHub master and its associated PRs.  It works as it should.

The association (Azure DevOps BUILD pipeline -> GitHub repository) is created when the Build pipeline is created.

Both Azure DevOps 2019 Services projects AA & BB are currently associated with the same GitHub repository XX via GitHub Azure Pipelines App.

How do I un-associate project AA with GitHub repository XX for the GitHub Azure Pipelines App?  Should I simply delete the BUILD pipeline in project AA to remove the association?

Comment: Hi, what about the below solution? Does it could help solve the problem? If yes, please consider [accept the answer to let other SO users know whether it is works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/541930). If you still meet any other issue. Feel free to leave comment.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for helping me!

For Azure DevOps 2019 Services for the Build Pipeline (for me), the UI is different (than pictured above) but it does provide the pipeline disable functions.

To disable continuous builds:

a. Click Builds (in the left navigation menu)
b. Click Edit button
c. Click dot,dot,dot button
d. Select Settings from the drop-down
e. Select Disable from radio button (Processing of new run requests)
f. Click Save button

To disable Pull Requests builds:

a. Click Builds (in the left navigation menu)
b. Click Edit button
c. Click dot,dot,dot button
d. Select Triggers from the drop-down
e. Select the repository under Pull Request Validation
f. De-select checkbox (Build pull requests from forks of this repository)

I will try this within a few days to verify it works.  I want to make sure all the GitHub pull requests are closed before I make this change.

Comment: Aha, these steps sound your build is configured by YAML, right? What I am used is Classic Editor(Updated this note in my answer). Thanks for this shared!

Answer (score 1):

If the connection method you connect the build with Github is using Github Repository as build source,

[image]

don't need delete the pipeline. Just disable two **options** under the pipeline configuration:

[image]

---

**Note:** What I am used and shared here is with Classic Editor. If what you used is YAML. Please follow Paul's steps.